# Why only from the second door the door close ? The first one stay opened

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The first script and the second both attached to the doors.
In this case I have 12 doors.
No matter what the first door of the 12 the player controller or a NPC enter the door it will open but stay opened. The next door the player controller or the NPC will enter will open and then also will be closed and then all the doors.

But each time the first door never close. It's working only from the second door each time when running the game.

On this script HoriDoorManager I'm using public static flag exitedDoor and set it to true inside the OnTriggerExit:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class HoriDoorManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static bool exitedDoor = false;

    private bool doorLockState;
    private List<DoorHori> doors = new List<DoorHori>();

    private void Start()
    {
        if (transform.parent != null)
        {
            Transform parent = transform.parent;
            var children = parent.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>();

            if(children != null)
            {
                foreach (Transform door in children)
                {
                    if (door.name == "Door_Left" || door.name == "Door_Right")
                        doors.Add(door.GetComponent<DoorHori>());
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter()
    {
        if (doorLockState == false)
        {
            if (doors != null)
            {
               for(int i =0; i < doors.Count; i++)
                {
                    doors[i].OpenDoor();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerExit(Collider collide)
    {
        if (doorLockState == false)
        {
            exitedDoor = true;
        }
    }

    public void ChangeLockState(bool lockState)
    {
        doorLockState = lockState;
    }
}
```

In the second script I'm checking if the flag exitedDoor is true and then start closing the door: Inside the method WaitToClose:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class DoorHori : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float translateValue;
    public float easeTime;
    public OTween.EaseType ease;
    public float waitTime;

    private Vector3 StartlocalPos;
    private Vector3 endlocalPos;

    private void Start()
    {
        StartlocalPos = transform.localPosition;
        gameObject.isStatic = false;
    }

    public void OpenDoor()
    {
        OTween.ValueTo(gameObject, ease, 0.0f, -translateValue, easeTime, 0.0f, "StartOpen", "UpdateOpenDoor", "EndOpen");
        GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play();
    }

    private void UpdateOpenDoor(float f)
    {
        Vector3 pos = transform.TransformDirection(new Vector3(1, 0, 0));
        transform.localPosition = StartlocalPos + pos * f;

    }

    private void UpdateCloseDoor(float f)
    {
        Vector3 pos = transform.TransformDirection(new Vector3(-f, 0, 0));

        transform.localPosition = endlocalPos - pos;

    }

    private void EndOpen()
    {
        endlocalPos = transform.localPosition;
        StartCoroutine(WaitToClose());
    }

    private IEnumerator WaitToClose()
    {
        if (HoriDoorManager.exitedDoor == true)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitTime);
            OTween.ValueTo(gameObject, ease, 0.0f, translateValue, easeTime, 0.0f, "StartClose", "UpdateCloseDoor", "EndClose");
            GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the OnTriggerEnter to this in your first script.

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collide){
    if (doorLockState == false)
    {
        if (doors != null)
        {
           for(int i =0; i < doors.Count; i++)
            {
                doors[i].OpenDoor();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You are not using unity's defined method when you remove the parameters of the method, so it is no longer referencing the same OnTriggerEnter.

It can then also be used to check what is triggering the on enter flag, because I am assuming you don't want any collisions to trigger this logic.